# Javscript to dynamically build HTML/SVG for mobile view

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

I have a full screen SVG image/mask reveal; it works great on desktop but it doesn't scale/fit on mobile devices. So im guessing the best solution would be to dynamically build the SVG and SVG container depending on screen width and have a mobile & desktop build. So i'm looking for advice and the best solution and if someone could point me in the right direction or know of an example I can look at.

```js
// DRAW SVG MASK /////////////////////////////
var svg = document.querySelector("#svg__bg");
var tl = new gsap.timeline({ onUpdate: onUpdate });
var pt = svg.createSVGPoint();
var ratio = 0.5625;

tl.to("#masker", {duration: 2, attr: {r: 2400}, ease: "power2.in" });
tl.reversed(true);

function mouseHandler() {
    tl.reversed(!tl.reversed());
}

function getPoint(evt) {
    pt.x = evt.clientX;
    pt.y = evt.clientY;
    return pt.matrixTransform(svg.getScreenCTM().inverse());
}

function mouseMove(evt) {
    var newPoint = getPoint(evt);
    gsap.set("#dot", { cx: newPoint.x, cy: newPoint.y });
    gsap.to("#ring, #masker", {duration: 0.88, attr: { cx: newPoint.x,  cy: newPoint.y }, ease: "power2.out" });
}

function onUpdate() {
    var prog = (tl.progress() * 100);
}

function newSize() {
    var w = window.innerWidth;
    var h = window.innerHeight;
    if (w > h * (16 / 9)) {
        gsap.set("#svg__bg", { attr: { width: w, height: w * ratio } });
    } else {
        gsap.set("#svg__bg", {
            attr: {
                width: h / ratio,
                height: h
            }
        });
    }
    var data = svg.getBoundingClientRect();
    gsap.set("#svg__bg", {
        x: w / 2 - data.width / 2
    });
    gsap.set("#svg__bg", {
        y: h / 2 - data.height / 2
    });
}

window.addEventListener("mousedown", mouseHandler);
window.addEventListener("mouseup", mouseHandler);
window.addEventListener("mousemove", mouseMove);

newSize();
window.addEventListener("resize", newSize);
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:700&display=swap');

body {
 min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: #1F242D;
 cursor: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}
.intro-svg {
 position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
 width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
 height: calc(var(--vh, 1vh) * 100);
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
}
.svg__container {
 height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.svg__image {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 cursor: none;
}
.text-svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  cursor: none;
  z-index:2;
}
.impact-text {
  font-size: 7em;
  line-height: 1.2;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.2.6/gsap.min.js"></script>
<div class="intro-svg">
          <div class="svg__container">
            <svg id="svg__bg" class="svg__image" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0" y="0" width="1600" height="900" viewBox="0 0 1600 900">
              <defs>
                <radialGradient id="mask-gradient">
                  <stop offset="80%" stop-color="#fff"/><stop offset="100%" stop-color="#000" />
                </radialGradient>
                  <mask id="the-mask">
                    <circle id="masker" r="250" fill="url(#mask-gradient)" cx="800" cy="450">
                    </circle>
                  </mask>
                  <mask id="mask-text" width="100" height="100" x="0" y="0">
                    <text id="masker" class="impact-text row-1" fill="none" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="3" x="10.1%" y="42%">A</text>
                    <text id="masker" class="impact-text row-2" fill="white" x="10%" y="55%">Digital</text>
                    <text id="masker" class="impact-text row-3" fill="white" x="10%" y="68%">Designer</text>
                  </mask>
              </defs>
                <image id="lines" xlink:href="https://i.imgur.com/1TQRj56.jpg" x="0" y="0" width="1600" height="900" />
                <g id="mask-reveal" mask="url(#the-mask)">
                  <image id="regular" xlink:href="https://i.imgur.com/7VtEKv3.jpg" x="0" y="0" width="1600" height="900" />
                </g>
                <g mask="url(#mask-text)">
                  <image id="text-before" xlink:href="https://i.imgur.com/7VtEKv3.jpg" x="0" y="0" width="1600" height="900" />
                </g>
                <circle id="ring" r="20" fill="none" stroke="#D74A53" stroke-width="2" cx="800" cy="450" />
                <circle id="dot" r="4" fill="#D74A53" cx="800" cy="450"/>
            </svg>

          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: The "S" in "SVG" means "Scalable" - you should be able to size your graphic as necessary.

Comment: You can also use CSS @media rules to adapt the drawing if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

just add

```
#svg__bg {
  width: 100%;
  height:auto;
}
```

andchange them with media query

don't forget to change

```
 <svg id="svg__bg" class="svg__image" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0" y="0" viewBox="0 0 1600 900">
```

without `width="1600" height="900"`

Comment: @Robbie you don't need to use it, just let css to 100%

Comment: what do you mean, remove the resize events and newSize and just set my css at 100%?

Comment: So i tested it when I got home and it works only on desktop, on mobile it scales the image down to fit the width and the height auto adjusts, not letting it stay at full screen.

Comment: you never said that you were looking for a distortion of your image, in this case it is by: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/preserveAspectRatio

Comment: Sorry I when I ask full screen on my original post, I meant full screen for all devices. I’ll look at that link in the morning and give it a try and report back.